# Sql query for Master Detail Records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have 2 tables:

- `Document` (columns `DocNo, Doctype, DocTitle`)
- `Registration` (columns: `RegNo, DocNo, RedDate, Location`)

For showing data I wrote this stored procedure:

```
CREATE Proc Show_Data_ByTitle
    @Title nvarchar(20)
AS
    SELECT * FROM Document WHERE DocTitle = @Title;

    SELECT * FROM Registration 
    WHERE DocNo IN (SELECT DocNo FROM Document WHERE DocTitle = @Title);
```

Now I want to show the result in gridview -asp.net page-

How can I do this?

Comment: From which table you want to show the data in grid view, document or registration  ??

Comment: Both of them ,in 2 grids

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think you need an inner join in your SQL Statement

```
SELECT * FROM
Document INNER JOIN Registration
ON Document.DocNo=Registration.DocNo
Where Document.DocTitle=@Title
```

Next if you are using ADO.NET to interpret the data you'll probably want a class specialised class to store the data like

```
public class DocumentRegistration
{
    public int DocNo {get; set;}
    public string DocType {get; set;}
    public string DocTitle {get; set;}
    public int RegNo {get; set;}
    public DateTime RedDate {get; set;}
    public string Location {get; set;}
}
```

Next you can use ADO.NET to get the data into your class

```
List<DocumentRegistration> list= new List<DocumentRegistration>();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString="YourConnectionString"
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Show_Data_ByTitle", conn);
SqlCommand cmd = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Title", "yourtitle"));

SqlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    DocumentRegistration dr=new DocumentRegistration
    {
        DocNo =  Convert.ToInt32(reader["DocId"]);
        DocType =  Convert.ToString(reader["DocType"]);
        DocTitle = Convert.ToString(reader["DocTitle"]);
        RedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["RedDate"]);
    }

    list.Add(dr);
}

//put this code where you want to load the list like PageLoad()
GridView1.DataSource=list;
GridView1.Databind();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i have 2 grids one for document and another for registration.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I thought you wanted the data in one table. In that case you can just simply use two classes instead to pick up the data and display it.